# Is there a way to move a window to another monitor using Python?

Tags: python, windows

I need to get a handle to a Window and then move it to my secondary monitor. Is this doable with python 2.6, preferably using the standard libraries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module to access the native Win32 API.  The functions you'll need to use are:

- [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all of the top-level windows in the system; search for the one you want and save off the window handle
- [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all of the monitors in the system
- [`GetMonitorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the virtual display coordinates of a monitor and to determine whether or not each monitor is the primary monitor
- [`MoveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to move the window to the desired virtual display coordinates, using the window handle you found earlier

Comment: Here's an [old article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0697/monitor/monitor.aspx) that's still relevant.