# How to get the display name of the monitor along with resolution in windows

Tags: python, windows, multiple-monitors

Is there any possible way to get the display name of the monitor when there are multiple monitors in a system.I used get_monitors in the screeninfo module to get the resolution of the monitors.Is it possible to get the display name along with resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the module you use only displays location and size of physical screens.

You could try using Powershell and subprocess to launch ps commands and parse their output like here:
[How to get info of all monitors with Python on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793805/how-to-get-info-of-all-monitors-with-python-on-windows)